# Bootstrap responsive form do not display columns correctly

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have a simple bootstrap form and I use row with 12 columns, that columns are divided in 3 different groups of 4 columns so, I should have 3 total columns

My code:

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<form asp-controller="Profiles" asp-action="Index" asp-route-returnurl="@ViewData[" ReturnUrl "]" method="post" class="mt-4 pt-2 needs-validation" role="form" novalidate>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-body">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm order-2 order-sm-1">
              <div class="d-flex align-items-start mt-3 mt-sm-0">
                <div class="flex-shrink-0">
                  <div class="avatar-xl me-3">
                    <div class="circle">
                      <span class="initials">@Model.NameAbbrv</span>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="flex-grow-1">
                  <div>
                    <h5 class="font-size-16 mb-1">@Model.Username</h5>
                    <p class="text-muted font-size-13">@Model.Roles<br/>@Model.Email</p>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <hr/>
          <h5 class="mt-4 mb-3">Manage Password</h5>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-4">
              <div class="mb-3">
                <label class="form-label">Current Password</label>
                <div class="input-group">
                  <input asp-for="ChangePassword.OldPassword" class="form-control" id="currentPassword" required autofocus />
                  <button class="btn btn-light shadow-none ms-0" type="button" id="toggleCurrentPassword" tabindex="99"><i class="mdi mdi-eye-outline"></i></button>
                </div>
                <span asp-validation-for="ChangePassword.OldPassword" class="text-danger"></span>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4">
              <div class="mb-3">
                <label class="form-label">New Password</label>
                <div class="input-group">
                  <input asp-for="ChangePassword.NewPassword" id="newPassword" class="form-control" required autofocus />
                  <button class="btn btn-light shadow-none ms-0" type="button" id="toggleNewPassword" tabindex="99"><i class="mdi mdi-eye-outline"></i></button>
                </div>
                <span asp-validation-for="ChangePassword.NewPassword" class="text-danger"></span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-4">
            <div class="mb-3">
              <label class="form-label">Confirm Password</label>
              <div class="input-group">
                <input asp-for="ChangePassword.ConfirmPassword" id="confirmPassword" class="form-control" required autofocus />
                <button class="btn btn-light shadow-none ms-0" type="button" id="toggleConfirmPassword" tabindex="99"><i class="mdi mdi-eye-outline"></i></button>
              </div>
              <span asp-validation-for="ChangePassword.ConfirmPassword" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4">
          <button class="btn btn-primary">Update Password</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

For some reason the third column just break into a new line, any one can see something wrong? I run into this a couple of hours and can not find the error. Help is very appreciated, regards

Comment: You are closing the row early causing the Confirm Password column to be excluded from the row. Remove the `</div>` before the confirm password column and place it at the bottom instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi you have nested to many things one inside the other please replace the below added code

```
<form asp-controller="Profiles" asp-action="Index" asp-route-returnurl="@ViewData[" ReturnUrl "]" method="post" class="mt-4 pt-2 needs-validation" role="form" novalidate>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-8">
          <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm order-2 order-sm-1">
                  <div class="d-flex align-items-start mt-3 mt-sm-0">
                    <div class="flex-shrink-0">
                      <div class="avatar-xl me-3">
                        <div class="circle">
                          <span class="initials">@Model.NameAbbrv</span>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="flex-grow-1">
                      <div>
                        <h5 class="font-size-16 mb-1">@Model.Username</h5>
                        <p class="text-muted font-size-13">@Model.Roles<br/>@Model.Email</p>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <hr/>
              <h5 class="mt-4 mb-3">Manage Password</h5>
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-4">
                  <div class="mb-3">
                    <label class="form-label">Current Password</label>
                    <div class="input-group">
                      <input asp-for="ChangePassword.OldPassword" class="form-control" id="currentPassword" required autofocus />
                      <button class="btn btn-light shadow-none ms-0" type="button" id="toggleCurrentPassword" tabindex="99"><i class="mdi mdi-eye-outline"></i></button>
                    </div>
                    <span asp-validation-for="ChangePassword.OldPassword" class="text-danger"></span>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-4">
                  <div class="mb-3">
                    <label class="form-label">New Password</label>
                    <div class="input-group">
                      <input asp-for="ChangePassword.NewPassword" id="newPassword" class="form-control" required autofocus />
                      <button class="btn btn-light shadow-none ms-0" type="button" id="toggleNewPassword" tabindex="99"><i class="mdi mdi-eye-outline"></i></button>
                    </div>
                    <span asp-validation-for="ChangePassword.NewPassword" class="text-danger"></span>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-lg-4">
                <div class="mb-3">
                  <label class="form-label">Confirm Password</label>
                  <div class="input-group">
                    <input asp-for="ChangePassword.ConfirmPassword" id="confirmPassword" class="form-control" required autofocus />
                    <button class="btn btn-light shadow-none ms-0" type="button" id="toggleConfirmPassword" tabindex="99"><i class="mdi mdi-eye-outline"></i></button>
                  </div>
                  <span asp-validation-for="ChangePassword.ConfirmPassword" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4">
          <button class="btn btn-primary">Update Password</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
```

my suggestion for you is to use simple way

```
    <div class='row'>
     <div class='col-4'> first set of code here </div>
     <div class='col-4'> second set of code here </div>
     <div class='col-4'> third set of code here </div>
    </div>
```